# What are the bright green patches in my Fescue grass?

Tags: grass, fescue

[image]I've started to notice more bright green patches in my lawn as we move towards spring.
[image: bright green patches in fescue]

How do I eliminate the patches?

Also, the border of my lawn continues to die. Could this be caused by an irrigation issue or from the edge trimmer?

[image: border of grass keeps dying]

Comment: You look to be in a mild climate, but I have to ask - do you use salt on the walk during the winter?

Answer (score 2):

While I can not say with any certainty what is causing the difference in color from one part of your yard to the next. I can say there are steps you can take at home to figure this out. I would start by getting online and buying a soil sample test kit. Test the soil in a region of light green grass and test it again in a region of darker color. I suspect as was suggested in the comments that you will notice a lack of nutrients in the light green areas. Assuming there is not an obvious cause for this, such as a slight elevation/depression of the top soil, then it can most likely be fixed by adjusting your fertilization on the problem areas.

I would assume the dying grass near the boarder of the lawn is caused by a clear separation between the dirt/grass and the boarder. What tends to happen in these areas is that the water, instead of feeding the grass, slips into the separation and drains out underneath the turf. An approach to fixing them would be to fill in those gaps about half way with sand and the rest of the way with dirt. Then remove the dead turf and replant new seed. Rinse and repeat until the problem areas go away, good luck!

Comment: Can you recommend a test kit?

Comment: @hammerman20 I would just grab whatever you have at your local home and garden center or you could purchase a product online like the: Luster Leaf, rapitest product.

Comment: I haven't been able to purchase a soil test kit. However, I'm noticing seedlings sprouting from many of these patches. I'd post a picture but I don't know how to post a picture in a comment.

Comment: @hammerman20 You haven't been able to purchase a soil test kit as in you haven't gotten around to it or you have had problems buying one? You can't post pictures in comments; however, you could edit your original post.

Comment: I am waiting for delivery of the kit. I have uploaded a better image of the patch. It has seed pods at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Light green grasses outgrowing the planted turf grass like perennial rye pop up often in the spring.  This grass is also identified easily as it grows faster than almost any variety of turf.  The grass outgrows the planted turf grass by inches every week.  This growth pace will continued through the spring into early summer.  The grass will produce massive numbers of seeds that will ripen and fall into the turf to grow again next year.

When the summer hot weather arrives this grass loses its vigor, turns pale and dies.  No amount of water will cause it to grow again and the grass is a winter annual.  It will not recover at any time this year after it has died.  The seeds dropped during the summer will supply the basis of the light green grass in the spring time, repeating the cycle.

This wild member of the bluegrass family, the dreaded Poa Annua, has struck again.  In the fall preemergent can be applied in early September.  The seeds lying dormant will not germinate, and will not explode in the spring.

No working herbicide is available to kill the Annua at this time.  Annua can be identified and slowed with an application of the herbicide Tenacity.  Be aware that the product slows the photosynthesis process causing the grass to turn white or light yellow.  Most turf grasses do not turn as white and some remain truly dark green.